# Oracle APEX Search Engine

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX 4.2.6  and  Oracle DB 11gR2

I've an interactive report showing the list of clients.

The end user can modify the Name of the client.

My issue is that I have to find a way to allow the end user to find the modified client by seraching it with his **old name**.

For example, the end user modify the name of client from **OLD NAME** to **NEW NAME**

In the serach engine of the interactive report, the end users must be able to find the client by serching it by its old name **OLD NAME**

Is there a way to manage this situation on the APEX side or Database side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very much a database issue, not an APEX issue.  When the user modifies the client name, you will need to record the old name somewhere: this could simply be an OLD_NAME column on the CLIENTS table (which would only support knowing the previous name for a single name change), or it could be a CLIENT_NAME_HISTORY table to which a row is added every time a client name is changed.

Having done that, your interactive report's SQL can then be modified to search both old and new names to find the client - for example:

```
select ...
  from clients
 where (name like :P1_NAME or old_name like :P1_NAME)
```

or

```
select ...
  from clients c
 where (c.name like :P1_NAME or exists (select null
                                          from client_name_history h 
                                         where h.client_id = c.client_id
                                           and h.name like :P1_NAME)
```

Note that I think you will need to create a page item for the name filter, because the built-in filter of the IR can only search data that is displayed in the report, which previous names will not be (presumably).

Comment: regarding your last sentence: OLD_NAME doesn't have to be displayed, but should be **selected** (it can be found in Actions menu - Select columns). User can create a **filter** which shows both "Displayed" and "**Other**" columns - OLD_NAME would be in those *Other* ones. Though, a *quick search* doesn't work unless it is, actually, displayed on the screen, you were right about that.

Answer (score -1):

Having additional columns might not be a "scalable" solution. What if another user changes the name again? And again? And again?

A better approach to store this data would be in rows that are uniquely identified by a combination of the primary key of the client along with an object version identifier - this could be a number or a time stamp or a date range. This is an approach that Oracle themselves use in many of its enterprise application.

Example of the data would look like below.

1.) Using Object Version Number

### Client Id     | Client Name | Object Version Number

1 | Bob | 1

1 | Sam | 2

1 | Ed | 3

---

Here, every time a user changes the name an additional row is created maintaining the same client_id value but incrementing the object version number by 1. The highest ovn represents the latest value. You could also have a column called "latest_record" and insert a value of Y when creating a new record to show that this is the latest record (resetting the value in the previous latest record to N). Similarly, instead of a number, you can simply store the timestamp and use that to determine the latest record.

2. Using date range

### Client Id | Client Name | Start Date | End Date

1 | Bob | 01-Jan-2017 | 31-Jan-2017

1 | Sam | 02-Feb-2017 | 02-Mar-2017

1 | Ed | 03-Mar-2017 |

---

In this approach, you are specifying the period of time for which the name was valid. A use case would be an individual taking the adopting the surname of their partner after marriage. In such a case, one name was valid from the time of birth to the date of marriage and another name was valid from the date of marriage onwards.

---

Once you prepare your datastructure in this format, in the apex report you just need to query on the single name column. I feel additional tables and columns are an unnecessary overhead in this case.

Regards,
SJ

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18743176)

Comment: @Umair Huh? Not sure what you mean. This is not a new question. This is an answer.